# Did Hermione shorten her life expectancy using the time turner?

Tags: harry-potter, time-travel

When Hermione uses the Time-Turner she is making her 24 hour day even longer by going back into the past a few hours.

Let's say her time spent in the past has added up to one year (I know it couldn't possibly, but other wizards may have). If Hermione was supposed to die in 2100, would she still die in 2100 or would she now die in 2099 from using the Time-Turner?

A.K.A. is Hermione aging equivalent to the hours she has gone back, or does her body "reset" to the age it was at the hour she has gone back to?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no cannon, but there's also no reason to suppose she's immune to aging. However, the time she relived definitely wouldn't approach a year - at the very most it might have hit a few weeks. Given witches and wizards have an extended lifespan compared to Muggles, I doubt she'll miss them!

Comment: I was using a year just as an extreme example since other wizards have probably used the time turner to that extent and since a month wouldn't really be that big of a deal. @DavidS

Comment: I thought you might be, I just included it for reference, since I'm not sure you'll get much for this answer except the Pottermore entry on time travel (which does indicate physical effects of time travel when making trips "further away" than we see in the series proper).